# How do I keep track of workers' tabs via pageMod? (or worker.tab lost!)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Using `pageMod`, I add a worker to each of my pages. Normally, I can find the worker matching the `activeTab` using `workers[i].tab == activeTab`.

However, I noticed that if I pull a tab out to a new window, the `worker.tab` becomes undefined and that is not good.

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScriptFile: ["./trace.js", "./utils.js","./pageWorker.js"],
//  attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
  onAttach: function(pageWorker) {
    attachPageWorker(pageWorker);
    pageWorker.on('detach', function() {
      detachPageWorker(pageWorker);
    });
  }
});
```

For example, when I open two pages, the tab IDs are `-5-1` and `-5-2` and the workers have matching tags `-5-1` and `-5-2`.

If I pull out a tab to a new window, the tabs become `-5-1` and `-35-1`, and the workers tabs are `-5-1` and `undefined`.

If I shove the the pulled out tab back into the first window, the tabs are `-5-1` and `-5-3` and the workers remain at `-5-1` and `undefined`.

```
function getPageWorkers(tab) {
  var result = [];
    for (let tab of tabs) {
        console.log(tab.id);
    }
  for (var i = pageWorkers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(pageWorkers[i].tab.id)
    if (pageWorkers[i].tab === tab) {
      result.push(pageWorkers[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Perhaps there is an additional event I need to attach to like:

```
pageWorker.on('moveToAnotherWindow',...)
```

---

**Update.** When the drag out is complete (this is in Windows), two events are fired, `pagehide` and `pageshow`. At that point the `worker.tab.id` is `undefined`.

```
console.log: attaching pageWorker in -5-1
console.log: showing page in -5-1
console.log: attaching pageWorker in -5-2
console.log: showing page in -5-2
<drag happens here>
console.log: hiding page in undefined
console.log: showing page in undefined
```

---

**Update 2.** When you move the tab to a new window, `worker.tab = false`!

```
console.log: attaching pageWorker in tab.id -5-1
console.log: showing page in tab.id -5-1
console.log: pageWorker.tab: constructor {}
console.log: attaching pageWorker in tab.id -5-2
console.log: showing page in tab.id -5-2
console.log: pageWorker.tab: constructor {}
<drag happens here>
console.log: hiding page in tab.id undefined
console.log: pageWorker.tab: false
console.log: showing page in tab.id undefined
console.log: pageWorker.tab: false

console.log: activeTab: -45-1
console.log: tabs:
console.log:     -5-1
console.log:     -45-1
console.log: workers
console.log:     undefined
console.log:     -5-1
console.log:  Error: no pageWorkers match activeTab
```

---

**Update 3.** When you kill the new tab in the new window, detach is called twice.

---

**Update 4.** Even with `.tab = false`, if I use `port.emit` on the worker, it responds.

---

**Update 5.** Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Use `jpm run` to start Firefox and go to Google in two tabs. Then drag out one of the tabs.

https://github.com/tofutim/pagepulla

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We generally try to provide answers that are tested and working. If we are going to try to verify our solution works *for you* it is **MUCH** easier to do so if we have your code to start from rather than having to make it all up. To do so, we each have to first duplicate the problem you are having then find a solution. Not having source code in the form of a [mcve] makes helping you a *LOT* more work. Without such code there is less incentive to find an answer for you. Please provide at least enough such that we could duplicate your console.log output.

Comment: @Makyen Use jpm run to start Firefox and go to Google in two tabs. Then drag out one of the tabs. https://github.com/tofutim/pagepulla

Comment: This is, obviously, a bug in the Firefox Add-on SDK. You appear to have [already reported it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1259292). From your question, I assume you are looking for a work-around.  Is it correct: you want a work-around that can be used in Firefox versions prior to the bug being fixed? One should be possible.

Comment: I haven't found a work-around right now, so in the interim I include in my processing every worker that has an undefined tab. I guess it isn't too bad.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "include in my processing" for all the workers with undefined tabs. What processing? It should be possible to determine the tab for any which have `typeof worker.tab.id === "undefined"` if that is information you need.

Comment: yes, I am using exactly that - currently I process every worker that is in tabs.activeTab as well as undefined, but if you can think of a way to know if the undefined is the activeTab that would be helpful!